# How to make Visual Studio automatically clear Javascript console?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio to build a mobile app using Cordova. The JavaScript console logs in VS are somehow persistent over different debugging sessions, which often causes confusion to myself. How do I make it automatically clear VS console logs every time I build?

I am using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: The browser console logging is persisting?

Comment: @IrkenInvader Not the browser console. I meant the Visual Studio's JavaScript console. I updated the question to clarify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you want to use:

```
console.clear();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh696634.aspx

Comment: If something is logged before the app is initialized you won't have the time to clear the console before loading. Is there a setting to clear it once you stop the build?